# How to change page in blade for JavaScript (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

This api is api.php.
My web and api are in the one project.
I want to change page in jquery request success result.
But I don't know what to do.
Could you do me a really big favour?

Code in the here :

```
<pre>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var account = $("input[name=account]").val();
        var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
            headers:{
                Key: "xxx",
                 Version:"1.0.0",
            },
           url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Login',

           data:{account:account, password:password},

           success:function(data){
           //I want to change page.
           }
        });
    });

</script>
<code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to do like this

```
success:function(data){
    $("html").html(data);
}
```

or

```
success:function(data){
    $("body").html(data);
}
```

but i'm sure that javascript from those pages will not work so you will fetch only html

edit: also this will actually not change your page it will fetch html from ajax request and replace your current content with it

to make actual rederict you should use `window.location.replace("https://faksesite.com/xxx.blade.php");`

Comment: Hi Olexander Pobuta,
   I want to change page like (xxx.blade.php).
So this method can do it?

Comment: this should redirect you to another page `window.location.replace("xxx.blade.php");`

but try both variants

Comment: Oh!!! That's great.
window.location.replace("test");
It's ok! You’re a lifesaver.